# Js Google Map Markers and Path Do not appear

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to implement a marker on a map, in a way that the marker will move along a specified path. I can verify that the map renders correctly at the right center and zoom, but the marker and the path do not show up. Any help/advise will be appreciated. I have tested on firefox and chrome.

My html code is as below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="map.css"> </link> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initialize" defer ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app-text"></div>
        <h1 center> Sendy Test </h1> 
        <h3 text-center> Question 1 </h3>
    </div>  

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

And my js function contained in the map.js file is as below :

```
function initialize()
{
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1.298982, 36.776811),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var image = 'https://images.sendyit.com/web_platform/vendor_type/top/2.svg';
    
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(startPos[0], startPos[1]),
        title: "Your driver",
        visible: true,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function()
    {
        animateMarker(marker, [
            // The coordinates of each point you want the marker to go to.
            // You don't need to specify the starting position again.
            [-1.297459, 36.776747],
            [-1.296193, 36.776726],
            [-1.296097, 36.779236],
            [-1.296151, 36.777637],
            [-1.296215, 36.776693],
            [-1.294252, 36.776586],
            [-1.294048, 36.776790],
            [-1.293973, 36.779118],
            [-1.292622, 36.779075],
            [-1.291844, 36.779049],

        ], speed);
    });

    polylineCoords = [];
    
    var startCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(startPos[0], startPos[1]);
    
    polylineCoords.push(startCoords);

    path = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: polylineCoords,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    
    path.setMap(map);
}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was because i had specified a wrong starting position on the map